# Angular2 Observable forkjoin: how to make a helper method for start and end loading?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a question regadring forkjoin.
My initial issue is to write a helper method which can accept multiple observables. This helper method should start a spinner service before subscribing to these observables and then end the spinner service after all data is received. 
The spinnerService itself will show a loadpanel during receiving data.

Without such a helper method I would write code like this:

```
this.spinnerService.show();
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.books = data[0];
    this.movies = data[1];
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  },
  err => { 
    console.error(err);
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  }
);
```

I want to have a helper method, let it call "loadMultiple" which will do the job with showing and hiding the spinner and handling the error itself if one ouccurs.
So my aim is to write code like this:

```
loadMultiple([
    this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
]).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.books = data[0];
    this.movies = data[1];
  }
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe` method accepts 3 callbacks onNext, onError and onSuccess. You can actually do without the helper method, just hide the spinner in the third callback:

```
this.spinnerService.show();
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.books = data[0];
    this.movies = data[1];
  },
  err => { 
    console.error(err);
  },
  () => {
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  }
);
```

If you absolutely need the helper method, I suggest that you hide the spinner in the `.finally` operator:

```
loadMultiple (observables: Observable[]) {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    return Observable.forkJoin(...loadables)
        .finally(() => { 
            this.spinnerService.hide();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

```js
function loadMultiple(loadables: Observable[]) {
  this.spinnerService.show();
  return Observable.forkJoin(...loadables)
    .do(() => this.spinnerService.hide())
    .catch( /*error handlig goes here*/ );
}
```

Please note the `...` array destructuring operator, and the catch operator to handle errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im new in javascript and taht stuff but it looks like to solve my issue. Will let you know when I have implemented it. By the way: Why have you used the array destructuring operator?